# CRMAF Filtering in CRM 2011

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to use CRM CRMAF Filter in a report for CRM 2011. But I can't find any examples on how to do it. What does the query need to be changed to to filter on Quotes and what Parameter needs to be added.

```
SELECT           Quote.QuoteNumber, Quote.Name, Quote.CreatedOn, Quote.CustomerIdName, Quote.OwnerIdName, SystemUser.Address1_Telephone1, 
                         SystemUser.InternalEMailAddress, Quote.Name AS Expr1, Quote.BillTo_Line1, Quote.BillTo_Line2, Quote.BillTo_Line3, Quote.BillTo_StateOrProvince, 
                         Quote.BillTo_PostalCode, Quote.BillTo_Telephone, Quote.BillTo_Fax, QuoteDetail.LineItemNumber, QuoteDetail.Quantity, QuoteDetail.ProductId, 
                         QuoteDetail.ProductDescription, QuoteDetail.BaseAmount, QuoteDetail.ExtendedAmount, Quote.DiscountAmount, Quote.TotalTax, Quote.TotalAmount, 
                         Quote.RevisionNumber
FROM            Quote INNER JOIN
                         QuoteDetail ON Quote.QuoteId = QuoteDetail.QuoteId INNER JOIN
                         SystemUser ON Quote.OwnerId = SystemUser.SystemUserId
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one reference you can take a look at:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/03/06/microsoft-dynamics-crm-pre-filtering-tips.aspx

You end up using the special filtered views that CRM creates for each entity.

```
SELECT name, accountnumber 
FROM FilteredAccount as CRMAF_Account
```

Another reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309722